# Два сайта на одном IP но на разных ПК

Tags: веб-программирование, ip

Есть два сайта. Внутри сети они находятся на разных IP адресах. Нужно реализовать, например, при обращении к www.test.ru на 192.168.0.110 а при обращении к www.start.ru на 192.168.0.111. В настройках обоих доменов указан внешний IP. Вход в сеть через Kerio (стоит на локальной машине с двумя физ. сетевыми: одна - внешняя, другая - внутренняя.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно настроить прокси-сервер.

Comment: а подробние? если можно.

Answer (score 1):

Запросы по 80-му порту содержащие (звездочка)[test.ru](http://test.ru)(звездочка) перенаправлять на 192.168.0.110, а содержащие (звездочка)[start.ru](http://start.ru)(звездочка) на 192.168.0.111?
В разделе HTTP Policy нет такой возможности? Вроде редирект там можно ставить... С Kerio работал 4 года назад, плохо помню)

Comment: это ты говоришь при обращении из внутренней сети, если я не ошибаюсь. а мне надо с внешней.

Comment: разве в Керио нет разделения интерфейсов, в плане возможности вешать разные правила на LAN и WAN? Вроде как Керио умеет управлять несколькими сетевыми картами...

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае можно лишь поступить так: из вне на один из сайтов будут обращаться на порт 81, а вы его днатите на нужный IP на порт 80. Второй сайт просто днат с 80 на 80. Если не критично что из вне будут набирать [www.site.ru:81](http://www.site.ru:81), то это ваш случай.

Comment: Подпись порта это критично. Необходимо обращение по чистому имени

Comment: Боюсь тогда, что ваш софт с такой задачей не справится.

Comment: Нужен совет какой софт нужен и как его настроить.

Comment: nginx, apache. настройка сведется к тому, что пишете servername test.ru а далее ProxyPass 192.168.0.111. Аналогично для другого хоста.

Comment: "servername test.ru а далее ProxyPass 192.168.0.111." это прописать в настройках nginx???

Comment: server_name test.ru;location / {  proxy_pass        http://192.168.0.111:80/; }

Comment: на один сервер отправляет а второй не могу добавить ошибка в nginx

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов на самом деле уйма.Например, настроить постоянные ссылки на сетевой диск\фтп и т.п.[Подробнее](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/consol/hdrguide/rusman/ln.htm).

Вариант неидеален - да, но чтобы предложить что-то лучшее, неплохо было бы узнать подробности.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант выше правильнее всего, ставим Апач и настраиваем в нем виртуальные хосты, на машине где стоит апач будет сайт номер 1 , потом настраиваем на удаленной машине шаровую папку через ФТП или САМБА (для этого не забываем поднять нужные сервисы на 2 компьютере) и конектим к ним компьютер номер 1, в конфигах апача указываем шаровую директорию, все.Не забываем пробрасывать порты на 1-ый комп и устанавливать автомонтирование для директории.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть два сайта. Внутри сети они находятся на разных IP адресах. Нужно реализовать, например, при обращении к [www.test.ru](http://www.test.ru) на 192.168.0.110 а при обращении к [www.start.ru](http://www.start.ru) на 192.168.0.111

Нужно создать [кластер](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-linux-ha/), это самое ровное решение

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый. Вынести один из компов в DMZ

Вариант второй. В правилах трафика KWF сделать два новых:

1. источник: внешний интерфейс, назначение: [test.ru](http://test.ru), служба: порт 80, действие: разрешить, трансляция: МАР 192.168.0.110
2. источник: внешний интерфейс, назначение: [start.ru](http://start.ru), служба: порт 80, действие: разрешить, трансляция: МАР 192.168.0.111<br>Будет ли работать - не уверен...<br>

Вариант третий. Для начала - домены зарегистрированы, так может где регистрировал. там и разнесут их по портам?Если да - смотри пункт №2, только в "назначении" указать "брандмауэр", в "службе" - порты, на которые разнесут домены. А если между Kerio и i-net_ом стоит модем - то сначала пробросить эти порты на модеме до KWF. И только потом делать проброс на Kerio.

Чот сразу и не подумал... Отмапить в KWF 80-ый порт сразу на ОБА компа (192.168.0.110;192.168.0.111). Ну а на компах уже name-based [виртуальные хосты](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)...

Хотя я бы, чесслово, сделал бы на ОДНОМ компе ДВА виртуальных хоста (чем сейчас и занят, тока развелось их уже пяток...))) и не парился... а второй комп под Nexuiz;)

Answer (score 1):

В FreeBSD эта служба называется **carp**, как в Линуксах - запамятовал...